# How to convert text box text from english to tamil using c# windows application

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

In my windows application i wish to convert the text box text from english language to tamil language which tools may be required to done this  thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support localization in your WinForm application the best and faster way to accomplish it is use resx files. You can find a lot of walkthrough and guides in MSDN pages.

If your text is static inside your textbox, you can use directly the tools in VS designer mode: set the `Localizable` property of your form to `true`, then select a language different from `(Default)` in `Language` property of your form; now if you select your textbox and put the localized string, this will be stored in a different resx file, autogenerated from Visual Studio to support the language you selected.

Once you build your application, satellite assemblies will be generated in subfoders (such as en-US or similar), remember to take these subfolders with your executable.

(If you're trying to translate a text the user put inside your textbox, I don't know how to help you)